# How to use flask or other webserver to change python code

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, webserver

hope you are all well

so my problem:
i have a DHT22 that is controlling a relay with its humidity and temp so when it is >30 GPIO17 must go HIGH , pretty simple but now id like to have web server run locally that i can change that 30 on the fly. and im just not sure how id do this 
have seen this link https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-own-python-dev-server-with-raspberry-pi-37651156379f/
which looks good however im not sure how to do this 
please help
thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "change python code". So you want a webserver and are not sure how to modify the behavior of your python code trough it?

Comment: Well if I understand correctly you just want to change the threshhold value '30' to something else dynamically. For that you can run your own webserver, but I feel like that's an overkill. You can also create a simple python GUI and create event on a button click to change the threshold value.

Comment: @ToniNurmi id like to change the value 30 with an input box or spin edit and confirm change with a button

Comment: @Batman id like it to be a web server as it will be part of an IOT system

Comment: First change your code to pull this information from a configuration file like a json or a database, not change python code(bad practice). Then create a function to reload this configuration whenever is changed or receive an cmd to reload. About flask is a simple endpoint structure, if you want something visual you need an html page you can use [jinja](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#jinja-setup)  and I recommend you to follow the [flask tutorial](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/) to understand how it works.

Comment: okay so id export my temps and humidity so a json file - check. now id create a python file with a function to carry on exporting or did you mean something else by "reload this config"